# How to change UUID after cloning a Mac HDD with `dd`?

Tags: dd, macintosh, uuid, hfs+

After 1 day of googling and try&error I give up and ask for help.

**Long story short**: I cloned internal HDD of my iMac (Mid 2011) to external SDD with `dd` command. Now I have two identical discs connected to my Mac. SDD is connected through Thunderbold. Choosing SDD from startup manager as the boot drive has no effect and iMac continuous to boot from the slow internal HDD. I guess the problem is caused by the identical UUIDs of both drives. Before editing /etc/fstab to prevent the internal HDD from mounting I need to change the UUID. How can I do that? Moreover I am confused by the fact that each partition has a volume UUID and a partition UUID - which one has to be changed? both? or only one of them?

**Full story:** I want to use an external SSD connected to my iMac through Thunderbold as my primary boot drive. Further I want to deactivate the internal HDD drive without opening my iMac. I cloned the internal HDD with `dd` command while I booted into the iMac from Ubuntu 18.04 live USB stick. When I try to use `tune2fs` to change UUID I get different errors depending on which partition I touch.

**sbd1**
`sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1 contains a vfat file system labelled 'EFI'`

**sdb2**
`sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb2
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2 contains a hfsplus file system labelled 'Macintosh HD'`

**sdb3**
`sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb3
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3 contains a hfsplus file system labelled 'Recovery HD'`

**sbd4**
`sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb4
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb4 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'BOOTCAMP'`

**UPDATE**:
I took the risk and tried `gdisk` to change UUIDs of the partitions on the external SSD. I used `x`  and `f` options of gdisk to randomize the SSD's disk&partition UUIDs. Checking the result back on OSX using `diskutil info disk1s1`, `...disk1s2` etc. it seems that this has changed each Partition UUID of all partitions. But the `Volume UUID` of all 4 partitions remained unchanged. (The Data did not get lost btw.). But I still have the issue that my iMac does not boot from the external SSD.  :(

Comment: I assume changing UUID without loss of data - (it this is possible at all) because cloning the internal 1TB HDD takes me more than three hours :(

Comment: tune2fs is only for ext2/3/4 filesystems, nor ntfs, hfs or fat.

Comment: oh damn, so what do I need in my case?

Comment: I also tried hfs.util from OSX ... `sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/hfs.fs/Contents/Resources/hfs.util -s /dev/disk4` as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/127191/how-does-one-change-the-uuid-of-a-volume-on-mac-os-x-10-6) without success

Comment: Another optionn I saw was  `gdisk` like in this [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154171/changing-hfsplus-uuid-from-partedmagic?newreg=6192446cb445448b970ad08e3b95d308). But I am afraid to try it because of possible data loss.

Comment: SOLVED my main issue (booting from external SSD) - see my answer below. Crucial part was to use `hfs.util` with correct syntax for IDENTIFIER to change UUID of bootable hfs partition which has the OS on it. `man hfs.util` was helpful here. NOT solved: changing the UUIDs of the other partitions which are not Mac file system.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change UUID of the most important partition with `hfs.util` and now I am finally able to boot from my external SSD. It was the partition which holds the Mac OS (El Capitan). If you cloned your internal HDD with `dd` like me it probably is named `Macintosh HD`

You need to find out the IDENTIFIER of the partition which you want to change UUID of.
Try `diskutil list` command and get something like this:

`>diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            699.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                300.0 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MacOSX                  699.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                300.0 GB   disk1s4`

In my case it's `disk1s2` with NAME `MacOSX` (I have renamed it from default during my experiments to mitigate confusion).

Before trying to change UUID you have to unmount this partition or the whole drive

> unmount partition
>
> `>diskutil unmount force /dev/disk1s2`
>
> or the whole drive
>
> `diskutil unmountDisk disk1
>   Unmount of all volumes on disk0 was successful`

Finally change UUID with hfs.util and remount the disk/partition.
The `-s` option will generate and set a random UUID.

> `>sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/hfs.fs/Contents/Resources/hfs.fs/hfs.util -s disk1s2`
>
> `diskutil mountDisk disk1`
>   or
>   `diskutil mount disk1s2`

Use `disutil info disk1s2` and `diskutil info disk0s2` to compare Volume UUID of internal external drive's partitions.

To boot from external SSD restart your Mac and while it restarts hold down the `alt` key on your keyboard (also called OPTIONS key) until you hear the boot sound. Choose your external drive (orange icon!).

With `df` command in terminal you can check whether your external drive is the boot drive

`>df

Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s2  1365908480 651731032 713665448    48% 81530377  89208181   48%   /
devfs                379       379         0   100%      657         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0         0         0   100%        0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%        0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s4   585932792  83152520 502780272    15%   284666 251392190    0%   /Volumes/BOOTCAMP 1
/dev/disk0s2  1365908480 644697952 721210528    48% 80587242  90151316   47%   /Volumes/Macintosh HD
/dev/disk0s4   585932792  83152520 502780272    15%   284666 251392190    0%   /Volumes/BOOTCAMP`

As you can see now `/dev/disk1s2` is mounted to `/` which means it is my boot or root drive.

From here u might be interested in how to spin down the internal HDD or how to prevent it from mounting at boot at all.

> spin down: https://superuser.com/questions/251969/disable-or-sleep-secondary-hard-drive-in-macbook
>
> do not mount on boot: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3686350

Answer (score 1):

The makers of Carbon Copy Cloner provide a simple (Mac) tool to change *volume* uuids (one at a time). The download link is on [this page](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/ccc-found-multiple-volumes-same-universally-unique-identifier).

I used it several times and had no problems.

Comment: +1 for this as it works with APFS volumes